# How come so many species in Star Trek universe have compatible communications technologies?

Tags: star-trek, communication

In-universe, I mean.

I understand about universal translators, but how come ship-to-ship communications are compatible, right down to the 3D presentations on their view screens? For example, Janeway talking to Neelix when they first meet, or Seven talking to the Qatai in Bliss, and those are on the other side of the galaxy from the Federation.

Comment: How come all airplanes in the Earth can communicate with any other ATC and airplanes? It's likely that the Federation has a standardized technology for communication that all ships will have to carry for intership communication. Even opposing sides have reasons to carry a communication device that can be used to communicate with hostile ships. Also, it would be grossly irresponsible to be so unprepared to venture to areas without a suitable communication devices for the area. As for the matter of 3D presentation, it's likely just an issue of film budget and simplifying irrelevant details.

Comment: @LieRyan your aeroplane analogy is flawed in that we have an international agreement on standards for communications managed by the [International Civil Aviation Organization](http://www.icao.int/Pages/default.aspx). No such agreement could exist from one side of the galaxy to the other. And your dismissal of the 3D question as being budgetary resorts to out-of-universe questions.

Comment: By your reasoning ICAO couldn't have existed. If a bunch of planets can cobble together to create the Federation, it would be a much simpler matter to cobble together to decide on a standard for communication device. In fact, having compatible communication devices would probably have been a precursor to be able to create an federation/alliance in the first place.

Comment: It does stretch the realm of believeability, however, when an alien species that has literally never encountered or heard of the Federation can interact with their computers the way Neelix does...does Neelix ever actually use the computers?

Comment: I think if your main concern is in operating incompatable technology, you should re-write your question title to reflect that - it gives the impression you're asking about communication in general, rather than a very specific case.

Comment: @Zibbobz to me, "communications systems" and "communications technologies" are almost equivalent (albeit that the systems rely on the technologies), but I have nonetheless changed the title as you requested.

Comment: This is likely because the purpose of communications is communication.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I agree up to a point, but look at how VHS and Betamax competed initially. Different technologies providing incompatible solutions to essentially the same problem. They were only resolved because of a) the small "universe" in which they existed and b) commercial pressures from consumers for a single solution. Those pressures don't exist when the technologies come from opposite sides of the galaxy with no direct communications between them.

Comment: Because, seriously, but boringly, there would be rather little of interest in the plotline if nobody could communicate w/ other species/ships.  There are some great SciFi stories which *do* center on a complete inability to communicate (Stanislav Lem wrote a few).

Comment: @ClickRick VHS and Betamax were competing standards, and more importantly products. If there were two fledgling communication standards competing for market share in your galaxy you'd likely be sure your ship could handle both. Furthermore, if a ship is advanced enough to analyze any electromagnetic wave in the vicinity, competing coms become a matter of software. Think MP3 vs WMA.

Comment: I've VTC. You seem to want to have a discussion about competing video standards.

Comment: In universe, the only reason for communications to fail between two parties who *want* to communicate, is first-contact. Known standards can be shared.

Comment: Darmok and Jalad at Tanagra.

Comment: I'll just mention a very quick answer that I've always assumed...

Comment: Oops.  Didn't mean to hit enter.  Anyway:  Quick answer - they have universal translators.  Computer languages are still languages.  Transmission protocols are still languages.  There's no reason that the same software that allows a universal translator even between alien races that they have not met before will not also work for methods of communication between computers that have never interfaced before.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess when you build a warp-capable ship, with the intent to meet other species, you will have some scientist, linguists and whatnot figuring out how to encode a video in a way, most people will understand. I'd guess the number of solutions a intelligent species can come up with is quite finite. If I were the project manager, I'd equip the ship with all of them. So when two foreign ships meet, it is likely that they have at least one solution in common.

As a second measure, I'd write a computer program, that searches for patterns in the incoming signals and compares them to the stuff you expect: Colors, wavepatterns, a roughly humanoid shape in the center of the screen... Then that program comes up with a matrix that translates the signals to a video.

We see barely video contact with a species that never had contact with aliens before. So it's likely, they all considered this compatibility-problem and solved it in this way. Over the time you will discover more solutions on how other species solved this problem and you can add it to your arsenal of communication strategies. After some dozens encounters you will probably have enough solutions to safely assume, that someone on the other side of the universe has at least one solution in common with you.

Comment: This is sounding quite plausible. After all, with the likes of Uhura and Hoshi doing nothing most of the time bar monitoring for "interesting" signals, and then establishing whether & how contact can be made, there's time for such a knowledgebase to be scanned for something appropriate. I was still surprised, though, at the degree of compatibility, even to the point where someone can walk right up to the view screen and the 3D-ness of where the other person is looking will "follow" them.

Comment: @ClickRick If I am correct so Seven will probably know of most communication-strategies there are: She is ex-borg and they have assimilated next to everything in sight.

Comment: `I'd guess the number of solutions a intelligent species can come up with is quite finite.`  Not really.  For example, the common standard for video encoding in modern Earth, YUV, is a technical mess.  It's based on the encoding scheme that was developed to allow color TV to be broadcast without being unplayable on black-and-white TVs, and makes very little technical sense if you're not familiar with that particular piece of historical baggage.  Who knows what some other species might come up with based on *their* historical baggage!

Comment: @MasonWheeler: The idea is, to think of solutions that would be easiest to understand for others. Think of the plate on the voyager-probe. Something very, very easy. How many solutions are there that you think everyone can understand? Not too many, I'd think...

Comment: It can be demonstrated that there are an infinite number of ways to represent a video signal, but given the massive computing power of a Starfleet ship and the fact that the aliens are probably actively trying to make their communications intelligible, I think the two sides' computers could probably work something out.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: It's not my job to figure it out, but... Maybe it's a good idea to send some prime-numbers first so the other side can figure out the numerative system you are using. Next you might want to send pictures of basic geometric shapes. Then some audio-beeps on frequencies, that are multiples of each other. Making it as easy as possible for the others to get your idea of the protocol.

Comment: @Einer - until you can provide evidence an alien species understood that Voyager and Pioneer plates, you can't say they worked. They still make assumptions about how we think aliens will perceive symbols and images.

Comment: @MasonWheeler YUV isn't that much of a mess and could easily be predicted.  Any civilization developing the technology as they go along is likely to develop grayscale video transmission first.  The idea of adding colour information on a subchannel and keeping the grayscale brightness values is quite obvious given this, and assuming RGB-type colour perception (which I'll comment on separately) there are only a limited number of logical ways of doing this (YUV is one, HSV is another but is much harder to implement; there are also a handful of YUV variants with different colour coordinate spaces)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that different species will naturally encode colours differently, because different species will have eyes that are sensitive to a different selection of wavelengths, and without knowing what those wavelengths are it does'nt seem particularly plausible to guess what colour is indicated by any particular representation.

Comment: There's also the assumption that most species will be smart enough to have the option to transmit some "barely encoded" data. If you send a raw waveform instead of doing any compression, for example, I imagine it wouldn't take much effort to play it back, never mind with the sufficiently smart computers at their disposal.

Comment: @Phoshi: When I contact a species with which I had no contact before, I'd broadcast using all strategies at my disposal. Hopefully they know one of them. So this shouldn't be just an _option_ but standard procedure in such a situation. And: Yea, compression is only an option after basic communication has been established. Same goes for encryption of course.

Comment: @HorusKol Unfortunately the Pioneer plate was used as target practice for a Klingon in Star Trek V.

Comment: "a roughly humanoid shape in the center of the screen" - I think that assumption is exemplary for why this answer isn't too convincing: Where's the "center of the screen"? Even if the video frames are sent as an uncompressed raster graphic, pixel by pixel, how do you know where one scanline ends and the next one begins? You can indicate that in the beginning of the data packet - width first, or height first? What's a "likely" aspect-ratio to guess the orientation? But before we get there, how do you know where one number starts and another one ends? How many bits make up one number?

Comment: All of these latter questions have to be answered before getting to the point of identifying anything in the "middle" of the screen, and they are still based on the *assumptions* that the other party considers a two-dimensional rectangular image the most logical choice. Still, the number of possible "likely" answers is rather large - large in a way that even with extremely advanced computers, the computational complexity would matter. Think of the *seemingly* simple and quick task to enumerate all possible states of a tiny memory of only 16 bytes.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: My idea was to _assume_ that there is such a shape in the center. Now with that assumption we look at the data and try to interpret it in that way that it suits this assumption: We puzzle it together so that this shape appears. If that works, we actually found out width and height.

Comment: @Einer: Something about that procedure reminds me of assuming that X is a witch in order to find proof that X is indeed a witch ;-) But I agree it may sometimes work like that, even though the flawlessness with which it is depicted on ST seems somewhat implausible.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Granted! :~/ It's an heuristic method and it should be supplemented with more heuristics. But if the sender of the data you are analyzing has the express wish that you can make heads and tails out of it, if he wants to make the job as simple as possible for you... It might work!

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is an in-universe result of a natural trend of technology to converge towards universal interoperability and dynamic reconfiguration.

Early spacecraft (such as Apollo and Soyuz) -- and even modern spacecraft -- require adapters in between their docking ports. In a Voyager episode (*Blink of an Eye*), a very Apollo-like pre-warp craft docks with the Voyager without any assistance from the crew. While it is not explicitly shown, this is the closest I've seen a Star Trek episode imply that Starfleet vessels are equipped with docking ports that can reconfigure themselves to complement any port presented to them.

I mention docking ports here because they are a good analogy for explaining **self-describing communications protocols** (the [Arecibo message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message) is a very early, crude example). Someday when we venture out into space in the hopes of communicating with other space-faring species, we're likely to have methods to both transmit *and* decode messages using protocols that first start by describing the protocol itself by some universal means (e.g. numbers, atomic weights, emission spectra wavelengths). We can assume that other space-faring species would follow the same reasoning.

To use yet another analogy from computers -- plug-and-play devices that don't require drivers.

Comment: +1 Why didn't Gene Roddenberry say this in the first place!

Comment: Plug and play devices only work because they are designed to conform to predefined standards.

Comment: as an aside, the Arecibo message is a horrible example. Teach  one binary encoding in your numbers 1-10 then switch to a different binary encoding when presenting actual information....

Comment: @Mr.Mindor, the Arecibo message was meant to be an illustration of the concept, not an example of actual technique, hence the adjective "crude". Plug-and-play too, is analogy that is not to be taken literally.

If you prefer a more factual example, deciphering ancient texts without a dictionary is one.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor don't forget how long PnP took to go from being snarked at as Plug and Pray due to widespread failures to the current situation of it (mostly) just works.

Answer (score 8):

I'd argue that the entire premise of the question is flawed. In-universe, we see a considerable [number](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Darmok_%28episode%29) of [episodes](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Little_Green_Men_%28episode%29) about the Enterprise having [issues](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Strange_Bedfellows_%28episode%29) communicating [with](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Fight_or_Flight_%28episode%29) alien species, either due to equipment incompatibility or Universal Translator failure (or a combination of both).

Out of-universe, all species seem to be able to communicate easily because **watching a linguist and an engineer trying to combine IT systems for 3/4 of every single episode would be intensely dull**.

[Roddenberry](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Universal_translator) established the idea that all species would have common communication systems in the original pitch for Trek;

> We establish a "telecommunicator" device early in the series, little
>   more complicated than a small transistor radio carried in a pocket. A
>   simple "two-way scrambler", it appears to be converting all spoken
>   language into English.

Jerry Sohl, the script writer for the "The Corbomite Maneuver" (the first regular installment of Star Trek, following the pilot episodes "The Cage" and "Where No Man Has Gone Before") explained further;

> "We were originally going to have [each crew member] carry a language
>   translator, which would fit on the wrist like a beeper, and no matter
>   what area of the universe they were in, the thoughts that the people
>   were thinking would automatically be translated into English as they
>   spoke. We got rid of that idea, and assumed that everybody did speak
>   English."

Coming up with a new language or a new IT system for each episode would be expensive, time-consuming and frankly unnecessary to the plotlines.

Comment: Unhelpful, as you concentrate on language translation (which I specifically excluded from my question) and even for that partly rely on out-of-universe arguments.

Comment: @clickrick - the premise of the question is flawed. We see them struggle with communication at least 4-5 times per season.

Comment: Q is about communication software. E.g. in our world we have digital vs analog. DAB, FM, GSM ... Guess a starship would have the capability to scan most spectrums and manage to extract unencrypted communication ... (An enhanced SETI :) Likewise one would send on a wide range of spectrums and formats when recipient has unknown tech.

Comment: @user13500 Even unencrypted, we have dozens/hundreds of encodings for video that are not compatible with each other

Comment: @Izkata: Then do not encode it, raw stream, or use encodings that do not give low entropy. We have hundreds of encodings, but they have advanced warp drives, replicators, subspace communication, tranceiver arrays, spectrum communication etc. One have to assume they use advanced mathematical models to analyse data for pattern recognition. If one then also send on thousands of bands and use thousands of formats and encodings the likelyhood of an advanced system would be able to translate at least one is plausible.

Comment: @user13500:  any representation is an encoding.  There is no such thing as a "raw stream".  Those "advanced mathematical models" cannot exist, and that is mathematical law.

Comment: @nomen: When one encode "*raw"* audio one also (usually) remove information, shuffle it around, add extra data to be used by decoder etc. *"Raw data"* is represented in a linear fashion with no data added or removed (within the spectrum of DAC). After digitalizing a wave pattern recognition comes into play.

Comment: @user13500:  You are missing the point.  Your DAC will have an encoding of the numbers as binary numbers in it.  And that encoding is not unique, or even "likely".  Put it this way:  there are 2^8 *encodings* of the set of numbers 1 to 2^8.  You are talking to somebody with a degree in mathematics, by the way -- not that I am arguing from authority, but **it is mathematical law**.

Comment: @user13500 If you simultaneously receive content on thousands of bands across the spectrum, why assume they are intended to be separate messages, or intended to be interpreted in a digitized way at all? In the analog world, we receive and process multiple bands to form one message naturally, think on visible light and our eyes.

Comment: @nomen - isn't it 2^8! (factorial) possible combinations/encodings?

Comment: @HorusKol: thanks, you're right.  For any encoding, a permutation of it is another encoding.  I stopped writing that half-way through and got foncused. :)

Comment: @nomen while that's true, certain encodings (e.g. PCM for audio signals) are much more logically obvious than others, and would likely be universal or near-universal.

Comment: @Jules: except that it would not be obvious on which frequency ranges such a signal would be transmitted.  Which means doing high bandwidth scans on highly entropic noise.

Answer (score 5):

On the first few episodes of DS9, the Federation has recently gained control of a Cardassian space station (Terok Nor, or as they rechristen it, the titular DS9).  You might wonder if Cardassia and the Federation are not even close to being allies why they would have a compatable terminal layout that either species could use.

In fact, they don't.  and in the early episodes, we see O'Brien doing a complete system overhaul constantly.  They even mention how unintuitive the control layouts are on the station.

That being said, we do see starfleet officers occasionally take over or work with non-federation consoles.  But it's also known that some federation officers are versed in multiple languages - which would allow them to interface with those consoles without problem.

As for Neelix, well, he probably just learned how to use the console to do what he needed it to do.  Voice commands (universal translator) would suffice for most of the duties a ship cook would have, and he probably picked up more than a few more complex commands during his tenure as 'morale officer'.

Comment: Good points, well made. I still smile when I remember Scotty's comment aboard the stolen Klingon ship (The Voyage Home) not being about the technology but about reading Klingon.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Einer and Richard's answers, but there's one point they miss.  Interspecies communications systems would work much the way the internet works today across international and especially interlingual borders. **Hard work and transfer of technology.**

1. As Einer points out, you'd design your output to be as easy to understand as possible, and program heuristics to understand the other species' (hopefully) simplified output.
2. As Richard says, in the extremely common circumstance where that barely works, it's a starting point.  Engineers and linguists on both sides of the divide roll up their sleeves and get to work.
3. Each new species' distinct technological and infological innovations would spread across the interconnected interspecies community.  Also known as: "*Hey, look at how they solved this technical / data issue.  That's pretty nifty, let's learn how to do that.  Hey species X, check out what we learned from species Y. It's better than the way you taught us, let's use that.*"

**Edit**

There is an inherent feedback loop, where knowledge gained from 2. and 3. helps one improve your output and heuristics in step 1., and of course step 2 would get easier with every addition to that knowledge base.

Comment: Commercial interests and a certain amount of `NIH` attitude will work against your 3rd point, but your first point sums up the practical aspects of why, on balance, it would work.

Comment: @ClickRick I think those will only slow the transfer of tech and ideas, not stop them. Also, remember that espionage is one of those "commercial interests". Think about today, and piracy in countries who don't share patent laws.

Comment: Agreed, on all points there.

Comment: I think your first point would probably be the largest factor assuming most species want to communicate with others so they would adopt what they would consider to be simple basic algorithms that could be easily deciphered. One related point I think you missed is that they would have a body of pre-existing algorithms for communicating with other species that they could draw upon and, given the frequent similarities and interconnections between species, they might already have a mostly working solution in their database.

Comment: @RonSmith I felt that pre-existing body of knowledge was implied in 1. and 3.

Comment: Ok, I can can see the implication but, as a programmer,  I would say that particular point has enough importance that it deserves to be called out explicitly. I'm not suggesting you edit your answer or anything, I'm just throwing it out there for discussion.

Comment: @RonSmith Too late.  I edited it. ;-)  I actually had meant to include it originally, and forgot to mention it explicitly by the time I finished typing the list.

Comment: I figure, by the time of TNG, they have enough of a database that the computer is able to tweak the algorithms 99.9% of the time without any human intervention. That's why they can just approach pretty much any alien ship and communicate without even thinking twice about it.

Comment: @RonSmith I'm also a programmer.  In code, feedback must be explicitly specified.  In life, the nature of time - things that happen in the past affect things happening now and in the future - makes feedback (in the very general sense) ubiquitous.

Comment: If you allow for AI systems (like Data) and near-AI systems (like the ships computer), then perhaps the feedback doesn't have to be explicitly specified, or maybe a better way to say it is the feedback is absorbed, and accounted for by the system based on the existing knowledge base and only the extremely rare exceptions that cannot be handled are kicked out for human intervention.

Comment: @RonSmith My statement was intended to be more general. Code is a structured environment. Effort is made to isolate everything, only allowing things to interact that are supposed to interact by design. Life is messy and everything is just tossed in one big bowl called: here, there, and everywhere. Interactions happen because there's no overarching architecture designed to prevent unintended interactions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14054/discussion-between-ron-smith-and-travis-bemrose)

Comment: I think the way the internet works is a somewhat unfitting analogy, as the whole world-wide network is essentially based upon technologies from a single point of origin. All the various technologies, interfaces and standards were defined first, then implemented based on that known specification by various parties, and that is why everything can communicate, very much unlike a first-contact scenario where such a common specification was not used at the time of creating the communication infrastructure.

Comment: And how is that different than the first time a newly spacefaring species encounters a species who is a member of the interconnected, galactic community?  You think that they'll be so advanced all the other species will adopt their technology?  The technology transfer will likely be significantly in the direction from the existing galactic community to the newcomer species.  When a new village in Africa or the Amazon becomes web connected, they adopt the existing technology.  Everyone else doesn't change to match them.

Answer (score 2):

To fill in a bit beside comments.

Your question regarding technological compatibility in communication with alien species does not exclude linguistic analysis but is in the core of it.

For one they would scan a wide specter of electromagnetic waves, filter out noise, record patterns and then start to decipher. There would likely be a rather sophisticated chain of software (or probably hardware) for pattern recognition. As one recognize an artificial signal this would be filtered trough various modules to try to tune in on a likely representation via converters.

Here the linguistic part is at the core. As one are able to generate translators one should also be able to recognize patterns which are translatable / has linguistic properties. (And sometimes it would not be possible.) One would perhaps end up with *n* candidates, and then it would be up to technicians and communications officers like Hoshi Sato to fine tune and try to isolate the correct specimen.

I do not recall exactly episodes, but there are some examples where they do this operation.

Over time the systems would be more and more sophisticated as one encounter new languages and communications models. A self learning system with some hard core programmers to overhaul and tune.

One would also tune ones own signals to accommodate the ones used by other aliens. Sometimes one manage to decipher the signals received and as such one can immediately do a reversal and send signals using same pattern. Other times it would be the other way around: the aliens would adjust their transmission to accommodate what they have managed to decipher.

For systems one use oneself one would clearly not use algorithms with known flaws and bugs. [NHL](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3247/hnl) has a very good point in regards to self-describing communications protocols. Such a system would be built from ground up with one goal in mind, and not use flawed and outdated algorithms or specifications.

Answer (score 1):

The self-learning capabilities of a computer system with a dedicated support staff, enough processing power, and a large enough data set could probably overcome most difficulties with the video encoding itself. The actual exchange of information is likewise solved by the finite means which communication could be passed: there are only so many wavelengths of light, so many types of radiation, so many methods which can employed to pass information from one starship to another at reasonable speeds.

A better question would be why all aliens have eyes, or have cameras, or have eyes and cameras that see in a comparable wavelength to our own. No computer could take raw video feed and translate it into colors the human eye can see if the proper wavelengths aren't in the feed. If encountering a species never seen before, which only sees in infrared, would they design a camera that sees outside of the infrared spectrum? If they didn't, then a Federation ship could only guess at what color the alien's skin is, etc.

Taking the premise that these species want to communicate, it is a good bet they would indeed have cameras capable of "seeing" in many wavelengths. But if they don't have eyes, would they even build cameras in the first place? If they are warlike (Kazon, anyone?), why would they willingly show potential opponents anything which could be analyzed to find weaknesses?

There is the additional concern with all aliens having vocal cords- virtually every species encountered can make noises discernible to humans. A universal translator solves part of this dilemma, as it could filter unheard frequencies to what the human ear can hear and translate the language to English, but only if the alien species makes noise to communicate at all.

Additionally, very few sentient species are not humanoid in the Star Trek universe. This could only come about with planned evolution or seeding planets with common ancestors. I read something about the latter being used to explain the Star Trek universe, but this begs the question of why there are so many superficial differences between species but not radically different ones which could have evolved as well.

At some point, we must realize concessions were made to make Star Trek possible. Actors are humanoid, audiences relate better to visuals than floating voices without video and prefer sound in space despite how little sound can move in the near-void, etc etc. Still, fun to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Because any species that has developed warp drive, will also have developed subspace radio.
"To echo an old saying, it's the only game in town." TNG Technical Manual page 98.

Once a subspace signal is identified, it is a simple matter of filtering out the voice data, which is then passed to the universal translator.  Most alien signals sent through subspace radio, can therefore be deciphered.

Think of it like ordinary radio: you can receive foreign stations, even though they may be using completely different equipment, all you've got to do is learn their language to understand what they're saying.  Even though they may have completely invented and built their own system, you can receive their signal and decipher it.

Because it is the only way it works, the technology will have some form of inherent compatibility.